# Pattern binding techniques in JESS?

Tags: expert-system, jess

So I wanted to create a rule that goes like this in pseudo-code

```
IF ?subject in ?course with ?schedule is still available 
   OR
IF ?subject in ?course2 with ?schedule2 is still available
THEN assert ?subject
```

I thought I could use connective constraints like

```
(or (and (course ?course) (sched ?sched))
    (and (course ?course1) (sched ?sched1)))
```

I have the following Deftemplate and Deffacts.

```
(deftemplate subject-information
    (slot name)
    (slot course)
    (slot prerequisite)
    (multislot sem-offered)
    (slot priority-lvl)
    (slot units)
    (slot section)
    (slot schedule)
    (slot day))



(deffacts subject-info
 (subject-information
        (name CS222)
        (course BSIT)
        (prerequisite Math101)
        (prerequisite2 CS111)
        (sem-offered 2)
        (priority-lvl 3) 
        (units 4)
        (section C)
        (schedule 1330-1455)
        (day MW)
        (add-day TTH))

 (subject-information
        (name CS222)
        (pre-requisites CS111)
        (pre-requisites2 Math101)
        (course BSCS)
        (sem-offered 2 3)
        (priority-lvl 3)
        (units 4)
        (section A)
        (schedule 1200-1325)
        (day MW)))
```

I have two deffacts of the SAME subject with different sections for different courses. I have a student with course BSCS, what I want is for the program to find a class for BSCS that fits his schedule, but if it finds none. It goes and check another class' schedule.

Comment: There is no value (subject name?) provided to match any fact in Working Memory, and the Jess code snippet doesn't refer to a template name, so this doesn't make any sense. Perhaps you edit your question to show your problem: the deftemplate, and facts that should match or not match.

Comment: I have already added my deftemplate and deffacts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you need that "or". You locate BSCS course events with one pattern, bind a schedule and use a student pattern to test for availability.

```
(subject-information {course == "BSCS"}
                     (schedule ?sched))
(student-information (free-schedule $? ?sched $?))
```

So I'm just assuming that student-information provides a list of free schedules. - The way the schedule is stored in your data may be all right for human readers but it isn't well suited for computing matches. Maybe there is a constant set of class times for each day, but even so matching days in one slot and times in another slot is inconvenient. And if start and end times can be anything, checking strings (!) according to the pattern hhmm-hhmm for one matching or encompassing (!) the other will need a function.

Comment: I already have the schedule figured out. I have a deffact for each time-slot. It is a must for the program to check first the schedule of a BSCS class then only second for the classes that is offered for BSIT. I dont want to use salience level because that would mean I will need to implement salience levels on the other similar rules.

Comment: It's impossible to advise well due to lack of information. For instance: Is BSCS-BSIT the only pair where the first should be chosen in preference? Is it possible to have third, fourth,... level of preference BSAA, BSAB, etc? Do these levels depend on the course names alone, i.e. BSCS always "beats" BSIT (no matter the student/semester and no matter the name)? A general solution would find all matches by time, insert them as facts and then find the best according to BSxx.

Comment: It actually depends on the student. Well there is a list of classes the student should take but due to some subjects he has failed he needs to retake that subject. Of course the program must check first the schedule of the class that is offered for the student's course and when it finds it is not available, it goes and check the class of another course.

Comment: There may be several sets of classes selected from the student's own course and from another course covering the student's new and flunked classes. There should not be any conflicts by schedule among the classes of a set. The best of these sets would have a minimum number of classes from other courses. - Considering all students, you have a nice planning problem. Trying to solve it by rules picking at one corner is going to cause dissatisfaction. - Of course, I may have misunderstood something...